# Pass map of fields into `new Account()`

Tags: unit-test

Is it possible to pass `Map<String, Object>()` or  something similar into `new Account()`?

I've created a testing utility class that gives me one-line `buildAccount()` or `buildOpportunities(200)` methods that simplify administration (if I add a new required field, I need to add the field in one place instead of every test in the entire org).

My goal: speed/efficiency

I know that `new Account(Id = xxxxx, Name = yyyyy);` is much faster than `Account acc = new Account(); acc.Id = xxxxx; acc.Name = yyyyy;` so I'd like to be able to pass in a set of fields from my test methods to be applied in the first way `new Account(Name = 'Test Account', mapOfAdditionalFieldsFromTestMethods)`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't constructor with the signature `Account(Map<String, Object> m)` available or the one you suggest. So you will have to add your own code such as:

```
private Account createAccount(String name, Map<SObjectField, Object> fieldValues) {
    Account a = new Account(Name = name);
    for (SObjectField key : fieldValues.keySet()) {
        a.put(key, fieldValues.get(key));
    }
    return a;
}
```

Using `SObjectField` as the key type (e.g. `Account.AccountNumber`) instead of `String` (e.g. `'AccountNumber'`) allows the code to remain compile-time checked and makes the interface a bit more self-documenting. (See [SObject.put](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_put_2) for a bit more background.)

Performance is usually dominated by the relatively high cost of database calls; as there is no "native" mechanism you really don't have much choice here.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider loading test data using Static Resource.

`List ls = Test.loadData(Account.sObjectType, 'myResource');`

You can read more about it here: [Loading Test Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_load_data.htm)

Comment: Is there any benefit to doing this other than saving a line or two of code?  I don't mind having it code-based since I've got one single test helper utility class that handles all the data creation/logic for tests across the board.  I like doing it that way because it gives me flexibility over how much data I create each time (I don't need all the data created for every test...)

Comment: Good question. It depends on your test Data. One advantage is that you can have different test data on different environments. You can still have helper class which encapsulate how test data is created. I assume that it will be faster, but I didn't test it.

Comment: Another advantage when you need set data in system protected field for some reason - https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181873&language=en_US

Comment: Ah!  Good to know about system protected fields, though I also like the JSON.deserialize() option...  I don't need any different info between test and prod, so I'll just stick to my test class methods for now, but I appreciate the input...  I did find @testSetup which intrigues me, since I do create the same test data in multiple methods at times